# Reusable components or widgets using some JS framework

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments, web-component, svelte

I want to create view components which satisfy the following list:

- can be included in any existing web apps written on any framework.
- are light weight
- are customizable by whoever is using it by passing some properties which are dynamic.

I want suggestions on which framework people use?
I went through ReactJS, RiotJS, VueJS, Web Components, Preact with preact-habitat. They didn't think they quite satisfy my requirement. I want to create something like what [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) has done.

Comment: Questions that are primarily opinion based will be closed

Comment: The **only** framework I know that is guaranteed to be compatible with any other JS framework is [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) That link will take  you to the download page.

Comment: You need some lightweight? use the template engine of underscore (https://underscorejs.org/#template). You can extend that for your needs

Comment: Stripe also uses <iframe> to inject their components on other pages. It wouldn't matter what you use to generate the html tbh. You could theoretically use anything.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find the link this one came from. It is old so there may be better examples. I think it should meet every one of your requirements. Execute functions with parameters using snake case.

Example with jQuery and Underscore

```
$.when(
 $.getScript("path/to/script.js"),
  $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
   $( deferred.resolve );
  })
  ).done(function(){
    _.each([x,y,z], function(){
      //
    });
});
```

(2007-2009)

```
<form id="bclform" onsubmit="return bcl_go(this);">
  <input id="bclline" name="cmd">
</form>

// $Id$

function arguments_to_array( args )
{
  var arr = new Array();
  for (var i=0; i<args.length; ++i) {
    arr[i] = args[i];
  }
  return arr;
}

function bcl_go( e )
{
  var cmd = e.bclline.value;
  bcl_run( cmd );
  e.bclline.focus();
  return false;
}

function bcl_parse( cmd )
{
  return cmd.split( /\s+/ );
}

function bcl_remove_blank_words( words )
{
  // Remove leading and trailing blank words.
  while (words.length>0 && words[0]==="") {
    words = words.slice( 1 );
  }
  while (words.length>0 && words[words.length-1]==="") {
    words = words.slice( 0, words.length-1 );
  }
  return words;
}

function bcl_run( cmd )
{
  words = bcl_parse( cmd );
  words = bcl_remove_blank_words( words );

  var last_cmd_word = null;

  for (var i=0; i<words.length; ++i) {
    var fun_name = words.slice( 0, i+1 ).join( "_" );
    if (window[fun_name] == undefined) {
      break;
    } else {
      last_cmd_word = i;
    }
  }

  if (last_cmd_word===null || words.length==0) {
    alert( "No such command \""+words[0]+"\"" );
    return;
  }

  var fun_name = words.slice( 0, last_cmd_word+1 ).join( "_" );
  var fun = window[fun_name];
  var args = words.slice( last_cmd_word+1 );
  fun.apply( this, args );
}

function bcl_jump_cgi( url, kvs )
{
  var url = url+"?";
  for (var k in kvs) {
    var v = kvs[k];
    url += k+"="+escape( v );
  }
  location = url;
}

//commands


function g() {
  var search_string = arguments_to_array( arguments ).join( " " );
  bcl_jump_cgi( "http://www.google.com/search", { "q": search_string } );
}
//g my search term
function g_i() {
  var search_string = arguments_to_array( arguments ).join( " " );
  bcl_jump_cgi( "http://www.google.com/images", { "q": search_string } );
}

function wolf() {
  var search_string = arguments_to_array( arguments ).join( " " );
  bcl_jump_cgi( "http://www.wolframalpha.com/input", { "i": search_string } );
}

function w() {
  var search_string = arguments_to_array( arguments ).join( " " );
  bcl_jump_cgi( "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search", { "search": search_string } );
}

function goto(o) {
  bcl_jump_cgi(o);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, you could choose to be framework agnostic and opt for Vanilla Javascript Web Components.

You can find a good introduction to [Custom Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-element) in this [Google Dev presentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements), and hundreds of answers on them in Stackoverflow.